# Using a Databricks dataframe with python formula to create a new calculated field write back to sql table

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm using Databricks to build my dataset in spark.sql and now have my dataframe formatted. I would now like to create a new column and apply a python formula to this dataframe and then finally write this dataframe to a table.

I have tried a couple of approaches but need some help in getting it over the line.

Databricks (python notebook) - the dataset

```
%python
df_my_dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("MyTable")

from scipy.stats import norm, chi2
def z(variable1, prob):
  if variable1 < 400:
  z_calc = [i for i in range (0,500) if chi2.sf(2 * variable1, 2 * i + 2) >= prob][0]  
else:
  z_calc = int(norm.ppf(prob,variable1,sqrt(variable1)))
return z_calc

df = spark.sql("select * from MyTable")
something = udf(lambda x: z(x['variable1'], x['prob']))

df = df.withColumn('test',something('variable1','prob'))
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("MyDB.MyTable")
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I'm looking to just add a new column to MyTable df with the new calculated field (function z).
e.g. A | B | C = MyTable and i want A | B | C | something | where something is the calculated field across the row, where i use variables A and B in the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok managed to solve it. It was the udf that was throwing me.

```
from scipy.stats import norm, chi2
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def fun_z(variable1, prob):
 if variable1 < 400:
z_calc = [i for i in range (0,500) if chi2.sf(2 * variable1, 2 * i + 2) >= prob] 
[0]  
 else:
z_calc = int(norm.ppf(prob,variable1,sqrt(variable1)))
return z_calc

df = spark.sql("select * from MyTable")

z_calc = f.udf(fun_z, IntegerType())

df = 
 df.withColumn("z_cal",z_calc('name_of_column_in_MyTable_variable1','name_of_column_in_MyTable_prob'))
```